# Flutter location returns speed and speed accuracy as -1

Tags: flutter, performance, location

I'm using Flutter and location package for measuring speed periodically in my iOS real device(iPhoneXS - maybe iOS 13) in debug mode and also running indoors.

This is my code.

```
class _TimerScreenState extends State<TimerScreen> {
  Timer? timer;
  int restMilliSec = 0;
  int setCnt = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bool canVibrate;
    restMilliSec = decideTimerTime(currentType) * 1000; 
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) async {
        // ... other code for another logic... //
        if (canVibrate) Vibrate.vibrate();
        setLocation();
      }
    });
  }

    void setLocation() async {
        Location location = Location();
        LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
        print("accuracy : ${_currentPosition.accuracy}, speed: ${_currentPosition.speed}");
        print("Speed Accuracy : ${_currentPosition.speedAccuracy}");
    }
}
```

I don't know what's the meaning of -1.
How can I get positive number for speed?
Other values are printed well.

[image]

Comment: Which package are you using for your location? https://pub.dev/packages/location this one?

Comment: Check the API documentation of the library you are using, but I would assume that a negative value on these would indicate that these are not available.

Comment: Yes that's the package I'm using. I couldn't find the meaning of -1 from documentation but I agree that it means that those are not available.

Comment: This can be normal sometimes in simulator when you are not on move. In such case you can simulate your movement with a simulator feature. on Mac it will be Feature > Locations then select any option except `None` and `Custom Location`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `CoreLocation` on iOS (upon which the Flutter [location package](https://pub.dev/packages/location) is built) specifies the meaning of -1 for [`speed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423798-speed):

> A negative value indicates an invalid speed.

and [`speedAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/3524340-speedaccuracy):

> When this property contains a negative number, the value in the speed property is invalid.

Thus, as you've deduced, negative values indicate an invalid or unavailable speed. *Why* your speed as coming back as invalid is difficult to say without more information.